# How do I click on specify recyclerview on androidx.test.espresso?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I have problem to click on specify recylcer view here my code, it still error

```
Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.recyclerLastMatchlist))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(1, ViewActions.click()))
```

This is the dependency

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'


androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2") {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: when i running the test, the error is " no views on hierarchy found matching.." @Sharj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your dependencies in your gradle, it looks like your app is using `com.android.support`, not `androidx`. If that's the case, you're getting `NoViewMatchException` because your test is trying to perform an action on `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`, which is apparently different.

So try replacing your dependencies:

```
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
```